# How to get my own server IP address with IO::Socket::SSL

Tags: perl, websocket

I need to issue local client in Perl for internal connection monitoring purpose, so for example (not intercepting, a separate client to an existing server):

```
my $srv_ip=????; # I know my server IP address, but this is general and may change, I want this to be taken programmatically somehow.
my $cl=IO::Socket::SSL->new($srv_ip:$Port);
```

1) I am inside an open websocket server using Net::Websocket::Server, but reading their spec I didn't found how to retreive my server IP addr and I think there shall be a much simpler way (maybe from %ENV, but I am not sure that this approach will be ok in every OS - it shall be portable, at least for Linux systems).
2) The server connection listener I also opened with IO::Socket::SSL:

```
my @crt=&SSLCerts(); die 'E101' if(@crt==0);
my $ssl=IO::Socket::SSL->new(
    Listen        => 10000,
    Timeout       => 45,
    LocalPort     => $Port,
    Proto         => 'tcp',
    SSL_cert_file => "$EF::Base/$crt[0][0].crt",
    SSL_key_file  => "$EF::Base/$crt[1][0].key"
) or die "E102: $!";
```

but in their spec I also didn't found my own server IP adress variable that I can use.

3) Note that the same pl program is for many systems, each one and it's port. Though they share the same host, the address is entered when loggin in from the client and NOT kept in any variable (this could help, but I think there must be a simple way to retreive it, maybe from %ENV).

What should I put in $srv_ip to get it work?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sockaddr()` method on the IO::Socket:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket::INET;

my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(
    PeerAddr => 'localhost:3306'
) or die "$!\n";

print inet_ntoa($socket->sockaddr()), "\n";
```

Example output:

```bash
$ perl dummy.pl
127.0.0.1
```

**EDIT:** please note that you have to use `sockaddr` on the accepted socket for the client, not the listening socket. On the listening socket you'll only see the address(es) to which it is bound to, which might be IN_ADDR_ANY (AKA 0.0.0.0).

Comment: Is it the same for IO::Socket::SSL? Do I must use inet_ntoa()?

Comment: See [IO::Socket::SSL#new](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/IO-Socket-SSL/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pod#new(...)): "You may use all the friendly options that came bundled with the super class (e.g. IO::Socket::IP, IO::Socket::INET, ". `inet_ntoa()` is only required if you want the socket address in human-readable format. You apply `sockaddr` to the socket returned by `$server->accept()`, i.e. the one you pass to `IO::Socket::SSL->start_SSL()`

Comment: If the client and the server listener ar ethe same computer, "localhost:$Port" may actually be enough, I don't really need to figure out what is the exact IP address the server is, right?

Comment: If that is enough, just use `sockport()` to retrieve the port number.